# How can I box all multiple-choice questions in a PDF so that they can be selected by the user, cropped, and then merged into a single file?

Tags: python, tkinter, image-recognition

I am currently working on coding a Python program that takes two PDF files, a question paper, and an answer paper. The program will initially allow the user to preview both papers.

[Here is my previous question (solved) relating to the above description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77353994/issues-faced-when-trying-to-render-two-pdf-files?noredirect=1#comment136371018_77353994)

The link for the question paper I'll be using:
https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/Images/520512-june-2021-question-paper-21.pdf

After confirming their selected files with a button, a new window will open, where each multiple-choice question in the paper will be individually boxed. I am currently working on this functionality.

Below is my current attempt, I am still trying to figure out the overall concept

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import re

def box_questions(pdf_path, canvas):
    pdf = PdfReader(open(pdf_path, 'rb'))
    num_pages = len(pdf.pages)

    for page_num in range(num_pages):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]
        page_text = page.extract_text()
        questions = []
        start_index = 0

        for match in re.finditer(r'^\d+\.', page_text, re.MULTILINE):
            end_index = match.end()
            questions.append((start_index, end_index))
            start_index = end_index

        for start, end in questions:
            x1 = 10
            y1 = (start + end) // 2
            x2 = canvas.winfo_width() - 10
            y2 = y1 + 20
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="red", width=2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PDF Questions Highlighter")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

pdf_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select PDF File")
if pdf_path:
    box_questions(pdf_path, canvas)
else:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a PDF file.")

root.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate any comments or suggestions provided to me.

Comment: Without seeing the PDF or the format of the information you're getting back, we can't possibly help here.